# Building a .net 1.1 project using msbuild

Tags: asp.net

The Web project we are working on is built against .net 1.1 framework.We would like to automate the build process for this project by using msbuild.However MSBuild only targets 2.0 framework. So how can this be done if we like to use MSBuild or MSBEE(this asks us to convert the web project to new version by opening up in Visual studio IDE)?We cannot convert the project to suit to 2.0 framework

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) to execute any command/executable from MS Build. So in this case, you can use devenv.exe (i.e. VS 2003) or csc.exe (C# Compiler from 1.1 version). Using devenv would be far simpler as you can use one line syntax such as `devenv /build release [solution file name]`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for devenv(VS 2003) command line reference.